# Bring textbox on top of canvases below it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I have three canvases and each one contains textboxes.
The first canvas contains a textbox bigger than the canvas and should be on top of the below canvases.
I tried to use z-index but it seems canvases are always on top on the textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could explictly create the item containers, i.e. ListBoxItems.

The ListBoxItems will be direct child elements of the ListBox's ItemsPanel and hence have a common parent element, which is required to make the ZIndex property work:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem Panel.ZIndex="1">
        <Canvas ...>
            ...
        </Canvas>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Canvas ...>
            ...
        </Canvas>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Canvas ...>
            ...
        </Canvas>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also apply some styling to make your code way shorter and easier to maintain. Should look kinda like that before applying Clemenses solution:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Canvas}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="500" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>

    <Canvas Name="firstCanvas" 
            Top="80" 
            Left="100"
            ZIndex="3">

        <TextBox Name="BigText" 
                    Background="White"
                    Canvas.ZIndex="6" 
                    Canvas.Left="50"/>

        <TextBox Canvas.Left="100"/>
        <TextBox Canvas.Left="150"/>
        <TextBox Canvas.Left="200"/>
    </Canvas>

    <Canvas Top="80" 
            Left="100" 
            ZIndex="1">

        <TextBox Canvas.Left="100"/>
        <TextBox Canvas.Left="150"/>
        <TextBox Canvas.Left="200"/>
    </Canvas>

    <Canvas Top="80" 
            Left="100"
            ZIndex="2">

        <TextBox Canvas.Left="100"/>
        <TextBox Canvas.Left="150"/>
        <TextBox Canvas.Left="200"/>
    </Canvas>
</ListBox>
```